# Remap keyboard keys to mouse wheel

Tags: keyboard, mouse

My mouse doesn't have a wheel, and my keyboard has some extra non-standard keys I don't use. I'd like to remap these keys so that pressing them has the exact same effect as mouse wheel up/down. How can I do this?

I use Cinnamon as my DE if it is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to accomplish this; I'll outline a couple of the easier ones. I'm on the Fedora 35 Cinnamon spin but will try to keep things generic so it is easy to adapt to Mint or other distros. If someone wants to do this from a different DE that does not have some way of setting global hotkeys for the DE, then you might need to find another way to call/invoke the binding (perhaps the link I include at the end?).

#### Option #1:

If you just want a simple GUI, you can try [Input Remapper](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/12/remap-keyboard-and-mouse-buttons-on.html) ([github](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper)). You will likely have to build from source if you are on a non-Debian-based distro but other than that, it should be simple to use.

*Disclaimer: I don't actually use this myself as I prefer not to load another gui app for a simple keybinding.*

#### Option #2:

Another [fairly quick to set up method](https://linuxhint.com/xdotool_stimulate_mouse_clicks_and_keystrokes/) is to combine Cinnamon DE's global shortcuts with `xdotool`. This is the method I use and it works quite well.

1. First, you will need to install `xdotool`. On Fedora: `sudo dnf install -y xdotool`. On Mint, `sudo apt install -y xdotool`.
2. Click on Cinnamon DE's "Start" menu or whatever you call the main app menu and go to Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts tab > Custom section.
3. Click "Add custom shortcut" button.
4. Give it a name (e.g. `mouse wheel up`) and enter the command: `xdotool click 4` then click the Add button.
5. Click "Add custom shortcut" button again.
6. Give it a name (e.g. `mouse wheel down`) and enter the command: `xdotool click 5`.
7. You should now see 2 entries for custom shortcuts in the "Keyboard shortcuts" section (upper half of window): one for up and one for down. Click on one of them to select it.
8. In the "keybindings" section (bottom half of window), double-click one of the "unassigned" fields and then press the key combo you want. I use `Super+<` for mouse wheel down and `Super+>` for mouse wheel up (or Super + `,` / `.` if you prefer), but use whatever works for you.
9. Repeat steps 6-7 for the other key.

It should work now as long as you are in a graphical session. If you need it in a tty / singleuser mode / other non-graphical session for some reason, check out [map2 by shiro](https://github.com/shiro/map2). It's a little more complex to set up but might work for this (admittedly I have not tested mouse wheel usage in a tty / single user mode - with or without map2 - but maybe it would work for scrolling terminal output?).